# Как изменять позицию при увеличении\уменьшении на div элементе?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как стоит изменить left/top при увеличении размера изображения на div?
[image: Стартовое изображение]

В примере красный квадрат, если мышь будет находиться на нём и будет запущено увеличение\уменьшение через wheel, то он должен оказаться на указателе мыши после, но не удаётся никак рассчитать насколько поменять left; top. Как сделать такое прямым js кодом, можно с jquery?
Вот что получается только увеличением:
[image: Только увеличение размера]

Часть кода с использованием angularJS и jquery.

```js
function addOnWheel(elem, handler) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        if ('onwheel' in document) {
            // IE9+, FF17+
            elem.addEventListener("wheel", handler);
        } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
            // устаревший вариант события
            elem.addEventListener("mousewheel", handler);
        } else {
            // 3.5 <= Firefox < 17, более старое событие DOMMouseScroll пропустим
            elem.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", handler);
        }
    } else { // IE8-
        elem.attachEvent("onmousewheel", handler);
    }
}
                    
addOnWheel($("#markupDetailImage").get(0), function (e) {
  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
  $timeout(function () {
    if (delta > 0) {
      scope.zoomOut(e);
    } else {
      scope.zoomIn(e);
    }
  }, 500);
}

scope.zoomIn = function (e) {
    scope.skuPopoverClose();
    var newZoomK = scope.zoomK / 2;

    if (newZoomK < 1) {
        newZoomK = 1;
    }
    
    var oldZoomK = scope.zoomK;
    scope.zoomK = newZoomK;

    var targetWidth = Math.floor(scope.imageSizes.width / oldZoomK);
    var targetHeight = Math.floor(scope.imageSizes.height / oldZoomK);

    // ширина\высота, в которую будет запись
    var sourceWidth = targetWidth;
    var sourceHeight = targetHeight;

    var width = Math.floor(scope.imageSizes.width / scope.zoomK);
    var height = Math.floor(scope.imageSizes.height / scope.zoomK);

    // width - новая ширина
    var xRatio = (width - targetWidth) / sourceWidth;
    var yRatio = (height - targetHeight) / sourceHeight;

    var offset = $('#markupDetailImage').offset();

    var left = (e.pageX - offset.left),
        top = (e.pageY - offset.top);

    /* закомментировал, т.к. после середины markupDetailImage вызывает не нужно смещение
    top = Math.max(Math.min(top, sourceHeight), 0);
    left = Math.max(Math.min(left, sourceWidth), 0);*/

    var outLeft = (left * -xRatio);
    var outTop = (top * -yRatio);

    /*только для теста*/
    var t = {
        sourceWidth,
        sourceHeight,
        width,
        height,
        xRatio,
        yRatio,
        offset,
        left,
        top,
        outLeft,
        outTop,
        movedX: outLeft + scope.baseOffsetX,
        movedY: outTop + scope.baseOffsetY,
        oldMovedX: scope.movedX,
        oldMovedY: scope.movedY
    }

    console.log(t);

    scope.movedX = outLeft + scope.baseOffsetX;
    scope.movedY = outTop + scope.baseOffsetY;

    scope.checkButtons();

    updateImageStyle();
    scope.AdaptFaces();

    return;
}

var updateImageStyle = function () {
    scope.markupImageStyle = {
        'background-image': 'url(\'' + 'data:image/*;base64,' + scope.currentRealogram.RealogramImage + '\')',
        'background-size': Math.floor(scope.imageSizes.width / scope.zoomK) + 'px ' + Math.floor(scope.imageSizes.height / scope.zoomK) + 'px',
        'background-position': (scope.baseOffsetX + scope.movedX) + 'px ' + (scope.baseOffsetY + scope.movedY) + 'px ',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '120px',
        'bottom': '1px',
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'padding': '0px',
        'cursor': scope.isAddStarted ? 'none' : 'crosshair'
    };
};
```

```html
<div id="markupDetailImage"
     class="col-lg-12"
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%; align-self: start; object-fit: cover;border: 1px solid red;"
     ng-style="markupImageStyle"
     imageonload="AdaptFaces"
     ng-if="currentRealogram">
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите код, с которым возникли проблемы

Comment: [Featured Image Zoomer](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/featuredzoomer.htm) вы это имеете ввиду?

Comment: [Zoom Image On Hover Using jQuery](https://www.jqueryscript.net/zoom/image-magnifier-on-hover.html) Или такой пример...

Comment: Код добавил, но пробовал и другие варианты, это попытка перевести https://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/. В 2 удаётся увеличить, но нужно в 1.25. И причём ломается при втором запуске, т.е. переводит вообще не туда. Если же менять размер перевода на 1.25 или на 4, то при первом запуске некорректен только background-position-x, при последующих запусках некорректно всё свойство.

Comment: @SwaD код добавил.

Comment: @DovgalDima, не совсем, для img немного не подходит, для div, что по ссылке идёт запись в отдельный div из img. Тут суть другая, используется div для изображения, и могут меняться background-size и background-position. Нужно рассчитать background-position, при изменении background-size.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопрос но:

Если тебе нужна координата указателя мыши, то это

```
document.addEventListner("mousemove", (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
});
```

Если тебе нужна координата центра, то можно взять за x - window.innerWidth / 2 и за y - window.innerHeight / 2

Comment: Нет, увеличение\уменьшение на wheel событии, так что все данные мыши есть. Не могу корректно рассчитать координаты, на которые нужно перевести при изменении масштаба с сохранением той же точки, т.е. поле background-position. Ограничений пока не ставлю, они будут вводиться позже.